# Rotating Three20 TTPhotoViewController inside TabBarController

Tags: objective-c, rotation, three20

Adding [Three20](http://three20.info/) *TTPhotoViewController* on an empty `UIWindow` Rotation were working like a charm.

But when I moved the *TTPhotoViewController* to be created from `UINavigationController` inside a `UITabBarController` it does not rotate at all.

I made sure I return **YES** for every `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` function.

Does Three20 Photo Gallery work in side UITabBarController with rotation?

---

***How am I doing this?***

```
[[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0];

TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeAll;

navigator.window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
TTURLMap *map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"tt://appPhotos" toSharedViewController:[PhotoViewController class]];
[navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"tt://appPhotos"]];
```

---

***Update 1:***
after reading some posts I can now rotate the images only inside the `TTScrollView` but the navigation bar is not rotating.

***Update 2:***
I have subclass-ed both `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController` to override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, but it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have weirdly solved my issue by removing the `TabBarController` from the `Window` object and when going back I add the `TabBarController` to the `window` again.

Answer (score 0):

You could just rotate the scrollView.. Anyway if you rotate the navController it would look weird when you pop the photoviewcontroller (if your gallery isn't rootViewController). I've rotated the scrollView and hided the navBar and bottom bar when going into landscape mode and it looks good.

Comment: very great idea, I reached this solution without thinking of hiding the navBar, as you said it looks weird if you don't hide the navBar, but my solution was extremely perfect and I have not touched the Three20 library at all.